# Symfony routage with slug url or callback

Tags: symfony, url, routes, callback, slug

I want to implement a url with a callback in it.
I have a url like :

> http://myserver.com/foo/http://callback.com

The problem is that the route don't match, the slug is an http url.

Here my controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo/{urlToRedirect}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginCallbackAction($urlToRedirect)
{
    die("TODO IMPLEMENT");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution with a requirements with regex :

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *          path = "/foo/{urlToRedirect}",
 *          requirements = { "urlToRedirect" = "[a-zA-Z1-9?*=*\/*:*.*]+" }
 * )
 *
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginCallbackAction($urlToRedirect)
{

    die("TODO IMPLEMENT");
}
```